# Facebook Icon tag unreadable on some monitors

Tags: bug, status-completed, sponsored-tags

It would appear that all / most of of the Facebook tags now have some icon image on them

[Facebook tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags)

This icon image is unclear and its hard to decide if it is infact a FaceBook logo / icon.

[image]

Comment: It was about time we had one of these again...

Comment: Yeah i know its been a while, had to check the date nope not a April 1 thing.

Comment: That looks like the [Facebook brand logo](https://en.facebookbrand.com/facebookcompany/) to me (at least [it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CF41j.png) reads "FACEBOOK", with some shapes below)

Comment: @Kaiido might be my screen but it looks like a non Latin alphabet here.   Shouldn't take to long for admins to verify if its legit Facebook, ad. if it is then i can just remove this.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for letting us know! This is indeed a Facebook logo, however, this is not really readable, so we'll need to check whether we might want to use a different file. We'll look into it and fix it.

Comment: FYI: Im on an ultra widescreen which may or may not be affecting the image quality.

Comment: Thanks, and fair point. I checked on my screen (regular mac) and it's less blurry but not readable. So not a great experience. So overall just something that has to be improved :)

Comment: I edited the title reflect the fact that its a bad image and not an invalid image.

Comment: I'd suggest just using the white F on a blue background they're also using as a favicon... that's way more recognizable

Comment: Yeah, I think that might be the best solution. We just need to agree with the client that they are ok with that :).

Comment: I see FB is rebranding the development / API side... Yay new looks. Who cares about recognizability, right? I get that it's their choice of icon, but really, an generic gray `FB` on a white background compared to the _universally recognized_ white `f` on a blue background?

Comment: @Cerbrus you read my mind exactly